How to unfreeze an SSD using GParted live?
I have an asus laptop which I wanna sell. Before selling it I want to run the secure-erase function using grparted live cd. But the ssd state is frozen and no hdparm command succeeds on this ssd. I don't find any related configuration in the bios settings. I'm starting to run out of guesses.. any ideas?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you run the following command, it either says "forzen" or "not frozen".
sudo hdparm -I /dev/xyz
If it's frozen, you cannot use the hdparm --security-erase command to securely erase the ssd before selling it.

Power-cycle the SSD. The 'security freeze' command is automatically issued by the firmware on boot (usually no option to disable it), and its effect lasts until the SSD loses power.
So if the SSD is inside your laptop, you'll usually need to take it out and connect to a USB SATA adapter – or to a desktop PC where you can unplug the SATA power cable.
(Depending on laptop, just unplugging the SSD and reconnecting it – with the laptop still powered on – might be possible or not.)

So I should remove it and attach to a computer as an external device, to overcome the boot settings? Any other method?

Because the system firmware almost never has a setting for this, all of the methods boil down to "power-cycle the SSD". As said in the post – depends on your laptop; if it's a SATA SSD, then sometimes it's possible to disconnect the SSD and connect it right back in. If it's not possible, you'll have to remove it and connect externally.
